Conditionally Show Hide 3 fields if first single line of text field equals "Technology"
(SharePoint 2013/2019)
While most of the Conditional Show/Hide jQuery solutions are triggered by a change in a Choice field, I am looking for jQuery that shows or hides three fields in a SharePoint Edit Form if my first field's value equals "Technology"
Summary:
If MyTextField == Technology,
show Field1, Field2, Field3,
else hide Field1, Field2, Field3

My 1st line reads:  (SharePoint 2013/2019)

And? For SharePoint 2013/2019 JSLink is the better solution built by Microsoft.

As it's the edit-form, you would require some extra code to check the form on load.
No need to use SharePoint Designer, simple edit the lists edit-form (https.//mySharePointAdress/Lists/myListname/editform.aspx) , add a Script Editor Webpart to the form page and add this jQuery.
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    // References to your fields (the columns internal name)
    const MyTextField  = $("input[id^='MyTextField']");
    const Field1 = $("input[id^='Field1']");
    const Field2 = $("input[id^='Field2']");
    const Field3 = $("input[id^='Field3']");
    
    // function to check if the column 'MyTextField' value is equal to 'Technology'
    function checkTechnology() {
        if(MyTextField.val().trim() == "Technology") {
            // True, show the fields
            [Field1, Field2, Field3].forEach(function (field) {
                field.closest("tr").show();
            });
        } 
        else {
            // False, hide the fields
            [Field1, Field2, Field3].forEach(function (field) {
                field.closest("tr").hide();
            });
        }
    };
    
    // as it's the edit form, hide the fields by default
    [Field1, Field2, Field3].forEach(function (field) {
        field.closest("tr").hide();
    });
    
    // trigger the function to validate if the column 'MyTextField' value is equal to 'Technology' on load
    checkTechnology();
    
    // check if the value in the column 'MyTextField' are 'Technology' on input, 
// trigger the function to validate again and hide/show fields if true/false
    MyTextField.on('input', checkTechnology);
    
});
</script>


Perfect! Perfect! Perfect!  Thank you!!

@ChasEpes Welcome! :)

Steps to customize with SPD:

Create a New Form for the list
Update corresponding fields  with a class name
Add a change event to MyTextField input control

To select all Field1, Field2, and Field3 in JQuery, add a class attribute

<tr class="myClass">
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Field1</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Field1" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Field1')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff3description{$Pos}" FieldName="Field1" ControlMode="New"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>



JQuery

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () { 
 
 $("input[title='MyTextField']").change(function()  {
 
        if($(this).val().trim().toUpperCase()=="TECHNOLOGY")
        {
          $(".myClass").hide();         

         }
         else
         {          
          $(".myClass").show(); 
         
         }              
 });

});

</script>


Expected Outcome


Thank you for this, but the $("input[title='MyTextField']").change(function()  { indicates that a change occurred. My case is where "Technology" may have been prviously added, so when reopening it in the Edit Form, the appearance would not triggger the script, I believe.
